# Cisco ASA cannot get "inside" vlan to internet through "outside" vlan

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-asa, firewall, nat

I just got my outside vlan configured up-and-running [See Post Here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/cannot-get-cisco-asa-5505-properly-configured).  I was able to get vlan 2 pinging to the internet 8.8.8.8 specifically.  However, now I honestly think I am misunderstanding what parameters I should be using ...  Here is my config so far:

```
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.1.10.100 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 74.xx.xx.225 255.255.255.248
!
ftp mode passive
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 10 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 74.xx.xx.230 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
http server enable
http 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 10.1.10.104-10.1.10.254 inside
dhcpd enable inside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
 policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
: end
```

As you can see, I have a PC connected and assigned `10.1.10.104`.  So dhcp is working correctly .. It just can't see the outside world!!

Comment: please add a specific list of protocols you want to work through the fw... or if you want to allow everything outbound, then just tell us that.

Comment: everything outbound .. on this vlan .. There will be more secure vlans later ..

Comment: Also let me rephrase ..  I would like any traffic to be able to happen inside the fw.  For instance traffic between port 1 and 2.  Also all traffic outbound on port 0 from port 1 etc .. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you should need is...

```
conf t
no nat (inside) 10 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0
dhcpd dns 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
end
wr mem
```

Since your inside interface is already a higher security level than outside interface and you are nating everthing, you should not need an internal or external acl.

Do a release / renew to pick up the dns setting, and then start surfing...

Comment: Thanks @Mike ... I messed it up at first, but it worked as expected!!

Comment: @zak, you're most welcome... good luck with the rest of your deployment and let us know if we can assist further